# How to make my JButton connect with my JFrame?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, jbutton

This is a BMI calculator. I have to separete classes Lab 4 and Lab5 (which is an extension of lab 4) However, I'm trying to get the JFrame(frame1) to show once I click the calculation button (CalculateBMI), after tryin and changing it a couple of times nothing is working and i'm hoping maybe someone here can help me.

```
**LAB4**

import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
public class Lab4 extends JApplet
{
    JButton calculateBMI, clear, resetapplet, displaystats, clearstats;
    Image img1, img2, img3;
    JLabel title, logo1, logo2, logo3, explain, showpic, empty1, empty2, welcome, BMIresult, genderOutput, height, weight, BMI, healthy, thanks;
    JPanel north, west, center, east, south, west1, center1, south1, north2, west2, center2, east2, south2, center1_1;
    JComboBox gender, feet, inches;
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("BMI Calculation ");
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame ("BMI Calcuylation: User Story");
    JTextArea txt1;
    JTextField txtfield1, txtfield2;
    Color violet = new Color(132, 28, 164);
    Color darkRed = new Color(148, 15, 15);
    Color lightRed = new Color(162, 101, 101);
    public void init ()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout());
        doNorth();
        doWest();
        doCenter();
        doEast();
        doSouth();

        frame1();
        frame2();
        setSize (975,500);

    }
    public void frame1()
    {
        frame1.setBounds(0, 250, 400, 300);

        doWest1();
        doCenter1();
        doSouth1();

        frame1.setVisible(false);
    }
        public void doWest1()
        {
        JPanel west1_1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());


        img3 = getImage(getCodeBase(), "HealthyMale.png");
        logo3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img3));

        west1_1.add(logo3);
        frame1.add(west1_1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        }
        public void doCenter1()
        {
            center1_1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(12,1));

            empty1 = new JLabel("");
            empty2 = new JLabel("");
            welcome = new JLabel("Welcome Sally Jones");
            BMIresult = new JLabel("Your BMI results are:");
            genderOutput = new JLabel("You are: Female");
            height = new JLabel("Your Height is: 5 feet and 3 inches");
            weight = new JLabel("Your weight is: 122lbs");
            BMI = new JLabel("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is: 21.61");
            healthy = new JLabel("You are: Healthy = BMI between 18.5-24.9");
            thanks = new JLabel("Thank you for using our Java Applet");

            center1_1.add(empty1);
            center1_1.add(welcome);
            center1_1.add(BMIresult);
            center1_1.add(genderOutput);
            center1_1.add(height);
            center1_1.add(weight);
            center1_1.add(BMI);
            center1_1.add(empty2);
            center1_1.add(healthy);
            center1_1.add(thanks);



            frame1.add(center1_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
        public void doSouth1()
        {
            south1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            JButton exitFrame = new JButton("Exit Frame");
            JButton storeResults = new JButton("Store Results");
            south1.add(storeResults);
            south1.add(exitFrame);
            south1.setBackground(darkRed);
            frame1.add(south1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    public void frame2()
    {
        frame2.setBounds(450, 250, 525, 300);

        doNorth2();
        doCenter2();
        doSouth2();
        doEast2();
        doWest2();

        frame2.setVisible(false);
    }   
        public void doNorth2()
        {
        north2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel history2 = new JLabel ("BMI's Caltulated and Stored since the last 'Clear Stats'");
        north2.add(history2);
        north2.setBackground(lightRed);
        frame2.add(north2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
        public void doCenter2()
        {   
            center2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));
            JPanel center2_1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            JPanel center2_2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
            JPanel center2_3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
            JLabel username = new JLabel("User Name");
            JLabel gender = new JLabel ("Gender");
            JLabel BMIcalculation = new JLabel("BMI Calculation");
            JLabel name = new JLabel("Sally Jones");
            JLabel female = new JLabel ("Female");
            JLabel calculation = new JLabel ("21.61");

            center2_2.add(username);
            center2_2.add(gender);
            center2_2.add(BMIcalculation);
            center2_1.add(center2_2);
            center2.add(center2_1);

            center2_3.add(name);
            center2_3.add(female);
            center2_3.add(calculation);
            center2.add(center2_3);



            center2.setBackground(lightRed);
            center2_1.setBackground(lightRed);
            center2_2.setBackground(lightRed);
            center2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray, 1));
            center2_1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray, 2));




            frame2.add(center2, BorderLayout.CENTER);       
        }
        public void doEast2()
        {
            JPanel east2 = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
            east2.setBackground(lightRed);
            east2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,20));
            frame2.add(east2,BorderLayout.EAST);
        }
        public void doWest2()
        {
            JPanel west2 = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
            west2.setBackground(lightRed);
            west2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,20));
            frame2.add(west2,BorderLayout.WEST);
        }
        public void doSouth2()
        {
            south2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            JButton exitFrame = new JButton("Exit Frame");
            south2.add(exitFrame);
            south2.setBackground(darkRed);
            frame2.add(south2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    public void doNorth()
    {
        north = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        img1 = getImage(getCodeBase(), "BMI2.png");
        logo1 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon(img1));



        //explanation part
        JPanel flow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JPanel flow1 = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
        JPanel flow2 = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Let's Calculate Your Body Mass Index (BMI)");
        title.setFont(new Font("MonoSpaced", Font.BOLD, 22));
        title.setForeground(Color.RED);
        flow.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        JTextArea subtitle = new JTextArea("The Body Mass Index (BMI) measures the weight status of your body in relation \n"
                + " to the fat. It is a simple tool that helps to calculate the amont of excess \n"
                + " body fat and the associated risk of carrying this extra weight. It can be aplied \n "
                + "to both men and women. ");
        subtitle.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        subtitle.setEnabled(false);
        subtitle.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        flow1.add(title);
        flow2.add(subtitle);
        flow.add(flow1);
        flow.add(flow2);

        flow.getBackground();

        img2 = getImage(getCodeBase(), "BMI1.jpeg");
        logo2 = new JLabel (new ImageIcon(img2));

        north.add(logo1);
        north.add(flow);
        north.add(logo2);


        north.setBackground(violet);
        add(north,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
    public void doWest()
    {
        JPanel west = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
        west.setBackground(violet);
        west.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100));
        add(west,BorderLayout.WEST);

    }
    public void doEast()
    {
        JPanel east = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
        east.setBackground(violet);
        east.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100));
        add(east,BorderLayout.EAST);

    }
    public void doCenter()
    {
        center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));



        //third row (3-rd)

        JPanel third = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JTextField select = new JTextField("Select to Show Pictures or not:");
        select.setEnabled(false);
        select.setFont(new Font("MonoSpaced", Font.BOLD, 15 ));
        select.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        third.add(select);

        JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("On");
        third.add(radio);
        radio.setEnabled(true);

        JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Off");
        third.add(radio1);
        radio1.setEnabled(true);

        JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox("Sounds On");
        third.add(box);
        box.setEnabled(true);
        third.setBackground(violet);



        //fourth row(4-th)

        JPanel txt3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel logo3 = new JLabel("Press 'Calculate BMI' or 'CLEAR'", Font.ITALIC);
        logo3.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 18));
        logo3.setForeground(Color.RED);
        txt3.add(logo3);
        center.add(third);
        center.add(txt3);

        //Fifth row
        JPanel fifth = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel name = new JLabel("Your Name:");
        txtfield1 = new JTextField(20);
        txtfield1.setEnabled(true);


        gender = new JComboBox();
        gender.addItem("Select");
        gender.addItem("Male");
        gender.addItem("Female");
        gender.setEnabled(true);

        //Adding Component Together     
        fifth.add(name);
        fifth.add(txtfield1);
        fifth.add(gender);

        center.add(fifth);

        //Sixth Row
        JPanel sixth = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        feet = new JComboBox();
        feet.addItem("Select Feet");
        feet.addItem(1);
        feet.addItem(2);
        feet.addItem(3);
        feet.addItem(4);
        feet.addItem(5);
        feet.addItem(6);
        feet.addItem(7);
        feet.addItem(8);
        feet.setEnabled(true);


        inches = new JComboBox();
        inches.addItem("Select Inches");
        inches.addItem(1);
        inches.addItem(2);
        inches.addItem(3);
        inches.addItem(4);
        inches.addItem(5);
        inches.addItem(6);
        inches.addItem(7);
        inches.addItem(8);
        inches.addItem(9);
        inches.addItem(10);
        inches.addItem(11);
        inches.setEnabled(true);

        JLabel weight = new JLabel("Your Weight:");
        txtfield2 = new JTextField(5);
        txtfield2.setEnabled(true);

        sixth.add(feet);
        sixth.add(inches);
        sixth.add(weight);
        sixth.add(txtfield2);
        center.add(sixth);

        //seventh row
        JPanel seventh = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        calculateBMI = new JButton ("Calculate BMI");


        JButton clear = new JButton ("Clear");


        seventh.add(calculateBMI);
        seventh.add(clear);
        center.add(seventh);
        center.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray, 5));
        center.setSize(500,300);
        center.setBackground(violet);       
        add(center,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public void doSouth()
    {
        south = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());



        //eighth row


        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset Applet");
        JButton display = new JButton("Display Stats");
        JButton stats = new JButton("Clear Stats");

        south.add(reset);
        south.add(display);
        south.add(stats);

        south.setBackground(violet);
        south.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,100));
        add(south,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}


**LAB5**
  import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.EventObject;
public class Lab_5 extends Lab4 implements ActionListener
{
    double H1, H2, W1, BMI1;
    String Height, Height2, Weight1, BMIndex;
    Image healthymale, healthyfemale, obesefemale, obesemale, overweightmale, overweightfemale, underweightmale, underweightfemale;
    public void init()
    {
        super.init();
        healthy();
        obese();
        overWeight();
        underWeight();
        images();
        JLabel BMIText = new JLabel("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is:" + BMIndex );

         Height = (String) feet.getSelectedItem();
         H1 = Double.parseDouble(Height);
         H1 = H1 * 12;

         Height2 = (String) inches.getSelectedItem();
         H2 = Double.parseDouble(Height2);
         H2 = H1 + H2 ;

         Weight1 = (String) txtfield2.getText();
         W1 = Double.parseDouble(Weight1);
         W1 = W1 *703;

         BMI1 = W1/H2;
         BMIndex = String.valueOf(BMI);  


         calculateBMI.addActionListener(this);
         calculateBMI.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void images()
    {
        healthymale = getImage(getCodeBase(), "HealthyMale.png");
        obesemale = getImage(getCodeBase(), "ObeseMale.png");
        overweightmale = getImage(getCodeBase(), "OverweightMale.png");
        underweightmale = getImage(getCodeBase(), "UnderweightMale.png");

        healthyfemale = getImage(getCodeBase(), "HealthyFemale.png");
        obesefemale = getImage(getCodeBase(),"ObeseFemale.png");
        overweightfemale = getImage(getCodeBase(),"OverweightFemale.png");
        underweightfemale = getImage(getCodeBase(),"UnderWeightFemale.png");

    }
    public void healthy()
    {
        welcome = new JLabel ("welcome" + txtfield1);
        genderOutput = new JLabel("You are:"+ gender);
        height = new JLabel("Your Height is:" + feet + "Feet" + inches + "Inches" );
        weight = new JLabel("Your weight is:" + txtfield2 +"lbs");
        BMI = new JLabel("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is:"+BMIndex);
        healthy = new JLabel("You are: Healthy = BMI between 18.5-24.9");

    }


    public void obese()
    {
        welcome = new JLabel ("welcome" + txtfield1);
        genderOutput = new JLabel("You are:"+ gender);
        height = new JLabel("Your Height is:" + feet + "Feet" + inches + "Inches" );
        weight = new JLabel("Your weight is:" + txtfield2 +"lbs");
        BMI = new JLabel("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is:"+BMIndex);
        healthy = new JLabel("You are: Obese = BMI of 30 or Greater");
    }

    public void overWeight()
    {
        welcome = new JLabel ("welcome" + txtfield1);
        genderOutput = new JLabel("You are:"+ gender);
        height = new JLabel("Your Height is:" + feet + "Feet" + inches + "Inches" );
        weight = new JLabel("Your weight is:" + txtfield2 +"lbs");
        BMI = new JLabel("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is:"+BMIndex);
        healthy = new JLabel("You are: Over Weight = BMI between 25 - 29.9");
    }

    public void underWeight()
    {
        welcome = new JLabel ("welcome" + txtfield1);
        genderOutput = new JLabel("You are:"+ gender);
        height = new JLabel("Your Height is:" + feet + "Feet" + inches + "Inches" );
        weight = new JLabel("Your weight is:" + txtfield2 +"lbs");
        BMI = new JLabel("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is:"+BMIndex);
        healthy = new JLabel("You are: Under Weight = BMI lower than 18.5");


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        if 
        (BMI1 <= 18.5) 
            underWeight();
        else if 
        (BMI1 > 18.5 && BMI1 <=24.9)
            healthy();
        else if
        (BMI1 > 25 && BMI1 <= 29.9)
            overWeight();
        else if
            (BMI1 > 30 )
            obese();

        Object obj = arg0.getSource();
        if (obj == calculateBMI);
            calculateBMI.getActionCommand();
            frame1.setVisible(true);



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you asking? What's your problem? How is your code not working? Where's the rest of the pertinent code? Please ask an actual well formulated question. A little effort goes a long way towards getting a decent answer.

Comment: i trying to make my JButton work so when I click it, it will show my JFrame @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: How can anyone help based on what you've posted? Seriously.

Comment: is the first time I post on this :(

Comment: Please read: [stackoverflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: But most importantly, try to read your question from our point of view: folks who have no idea what you're trying to do or what your program does, or what your code looks like. We only know what you tell us and what you show us. You will want to tell -- explain actually, show some paragraphs -- and show -- show more pertinent code, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: do you think you might be able to help me now @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: You appear to be severely over-complicating things in the code that you've posted, and I recommend that you try to first of all simplify and separate what you can. But most important, I don't see why you're having the Lab_5 class extend Lab4 as that doesn't make sense to me. Have separate classes yes, one to perhaps have a display and the other to do calculations, or one to display one *view* and the other to display another *view*, but inheritance does not appear to have any place here.

Comment: the requirement were to extend Lab4 without making changes on it so that is why looks really unorganized @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: What are the exact requirements?

Comment: well the first one is to extend lab 4 at lab 5, then lab5 need to have the math function working. so it basically need to have the user input working. Need to show what is the BMI Index and tell the user if is obese, healthy ... now mine works to the point that all the methods are fine, and no error occurs, however I have no idea how to make frame1 pop out after the user clicks on CalculateBMI. and that part I tried to do at the very bottom of lab5 @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: How can Lab_5 work when you appear to be extracting data from the feet JComboBox in its `init()` method, meaning you're trying to get the user's selection **before** he's had a chance to select anything? Also your code creates new components but puts them nowhere. Sorry to be blunt, but it appears to be a mess.

Comment: so what would be the best way for me to fix that? I'm sorry about this, I'm new to programming languages, however I really want to learn. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to display frame1 from within the calculateBMI button's press, then in your Lab5, add an ActionListener to the button that does your calculations, and that then displays the JFrame. Something as simple as:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Lab5b extends Lab4 {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        // add an ActionListener to the button
        calculateBMI.addActionListener(e -> {calcBmiAction(e);});
    }

    private void calcBmiAction(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO calculations for BMI here. I'll leave this for you to do.

        // frame1 displayed:            
        frame1.setVisible(true);  // that's all that's needed    
    }
}
```

And you probably shouldn't create all those components that you're doing in your Lab5 class, but rather should change the state of existing components.

But also understand that this is bad program design that your instructor is having you do.